# SearchBar dims screen after searching

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a xamarin forms app, using the searchbar tag to create a searchbar. For some reason, once I hit search and there is text in the searchbar, the whole screen gets a grayish tint... i have no clue why this is happening and did not find anything on the internet...

[Before Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1FcX.png)

[After Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5se2j.png)

Please halp (•_•)

Comment: I dont see any grayish tint in the pictures

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking questions. Also read [How do I ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using an external keyboard or a mirroring software (Vysor) the grayish ton appears after hiting enter.

The same behvior can happen with an Entry. Try using mouse to confirm search.

Comment: Wow, didn't think that would work, but it did! Thanks a lot!!!